# How to check performance of downloading a file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, performance, curl, streaming, performance-testing

I've write a video streaming server with NodeJS recently.
I wanna to check the performance of streaming with a virtualizing scenario
for example I can run a thousand `curl` command to fetch a video and check cpu usage of the running nodejs process. but I don't know how to run curl parallel for virtualizing what happened when 1000 users stream my videos.

help me if you have another solution for this. I don't know how to check the performance of my server for many users.

Comment: I would suggest to explore [`autocannon`](https://github.com/mcollina/autocannon) since every fake-user should open a socket to your server

Answer (score 2):

You can kick off 1000 simultaneous curl commands using i.e. [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) however I don't think it's the best way to do a proper load test because you won't have any performance metrics which can be analysed and correlated

Also sending 1000 requests is a good example of a [spike test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Spike_testing) while "classic" load test would be:

1. Starting with 1 thread (virtual user)
2. Gradually increasing the load up to 1000 (or whatever is the anticipated number of users of your application)
3. Holding the load for a certain amount of time
4. Gradually decreasing the load to 0

This way you will be able to correlate the increasing load with increasing throughput (number of requests per second), response time, error rate, see whether application gets back to normal when the load decreases, are there [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), etc.

So I would recommend going for a [dedicated load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) which provides possibility to define flexible workload scenarios and outputs nice tables and charts allowing you to perform the test results analysis